# SSMS 2012 hanging when opening multiple query windows or files

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I recently upgraded from 2005 to 2012 (about 10 months).  When I first started using SSMS2012 it worked great was able to open multiple windows in a particular database.  For about that last 2-3 months SSMS hangs when I try to open more than 1 query window or open a file.  It is random but happens a majority of the time.  I have been able to interrupt the hang a few times.  When I interrupt it I get the login screen and it sits there trying to log in apparently unsuccessfully.  If I cancel the login and try it again with the same entries it connects just fine and things are great, but I have to do this for every window and I cannot often break into that screen before it stops responding.

I have searched extensively and have not found an answer to this problem.  It only appears to be happening to a particular instance.  The instance does not show any signs of issues, has been rebooted and configuration checked for inconsistencies, etc.  I am at a loss.  If anyone has experienced this and has been able to resolve it I would appreciate a response.

Again this is a fresh install of 2012 standard with 2005 imported databases.  All indications show that it is working fine.  compatibility level for a majority of the databases are still 90, until I can clear them for 11 with the software they house.  I have a test environment with the restored versions on a different server and no issues result from that instance - I can open up multiples without incident.  My belief is it is something with that particular instance, but I am not sure where else to look.

Thank you in advance.